# Theano dataset dimensions error when passing into function

Tags: neural-network, theano, lasagne

Using the the example network of a mlp with 2 hidden layers and two drop outs 
so my load_data() function has 400 rows of 20 features and my label dataset is just 400 rows of one variable that will be split into X_train X_test y_train_y_test and some taken out for validation

my lasagne input layer is :

```
l_in = lasagne.layers.InputLayer(shape=(None, 20), input_var=input_var)
```

and my train function is `train_fn = theano.function([input_var, target_var], loss, updates=updates, allow_input_downcast=True)`

at around here my program skips: `train_err += train_fn(inputs, targets)`

```
'Wrong number of dimensions: expected 1, got 2 with shape (20, 1).')
```

the 20, 1 I understand, as I passed in twenty values on one side and 1 value in the labels side, but I thought theano autonmatically flattened each array?

what can I do to fix this?
any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inputs that you pass to `train_fn()` should be an `ndarray` with shape `(n, 20)`, where `n` is the number of examples in your minibatch. The targets should be an `ndarray` with shape `(n)` (note that shapes `(1, n)` and `(n, 1)` won't work). Try double checking that the arrays you actually pass to the function match these shapes.

Comment: thanks man, I sorted this problem out before I went to bed, and you ended up being right, the train_fn function was taking in an ndarray of (1,20), changed it to 20 in the minibatch maker function so now they align... although I have hit another problem if youre game to help, check my new question, ill mark your current answer as the one that worked for me